# How do I improve the load speed of images that use a URL as source?

Tags: html, reactjs, performance

I have an image URL, and I'm providing it to the image src attribute on a modal component.
When the modal opens, there is a black card for a few seconds till the image shown.

How can I make it visible faster? I guess I cannot use spinner because it is not a fetch process.

This is my component, the image is just a URL.

```
const Modal = ({
  closeModal,
  runtime,
  title,
  rating,
  image,
  description,
}: ModalProps) => {
  const {
    movie: { backToListLabel },
  } = dictionary

  const getRating = () => {
    return `${rating}/${TOP_RATING}`
  }

  return (
    <ModalOverlay data-testid="modal">
      <ModalContent>
        <MovieCover
          alt="movie-cover"
          src={image}
        ></MovieCover>
        <MovideDetailsContainer>
          <MovieDetails>
            <Title>{title}</Title>
            <Duration>{runtime}</Duration>
            {rating && (
              <RatingContainer>
                <RatingIcon src={ratingIcon} />
                <Rating>{getRating()}</Rating>
              </RatingContainer>
            )}
            <Description dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }} />
          </MovieDetails>
          <BackToList
            onClick={closeModal}
            data-testid="back-to-list"
          >
            <BackToListIcon src={arrowIcon} />
            <BackToListTitle>{backToListLabel}</BackToListTitle>
          </BackToList>
        </MovideDetailsContainer>
      </ModalContent>
    </ModalOverlay>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

Comment: I like this workaround: To let the browser pre-load the image you could create an img tag that is shown at 1px x 1px size at position -10000px,-10000px or something like that before the overlay loads. Don't use 0x0 size, an optimization running in some browsers may determine to skip an asset that has no size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<link rel="preload" as="image" href="..." />`. Have a look at this [article on web.dev](https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/).

Comment: OP should also check supported browsers if old browsers are relevant: [caniuse - preload](https://caniuse.com/link-rel-preload)

Comment: Well, its not loading at all now, it seems like the link is set to display:none.

Comment: Protip: [Never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/).

Comment: @MishaOk The link is in addition to the img tag, preferably in the Head